# Sometimes my KTM starts and sometimes it doesn't

Tags: engine, motorcycle, starting, ktm

Sometimes my KTM starts and sometimes it doesn't

I have a problem on my 2015 KTM 125EXC. Six days and the weird thing is that it starts sometimes. It only kicks starts when I try to start it. It just sits there and kicks and kicks and kicks so its not the battery since their is no electric start or battery. I have cleaned my air filter. It has not been sitting so it can't be that, I think. Can someone please help me.

Sorry about my English its not my main language.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the spark plug?

Comment: How many hours has it done? Consider the basics: compression, fuel & ignition. Does it have fresh fuel? Does it have a strong spark?

Comment: @ineedhelp   peter has some good questions, can you answer them?Perhaps someone can help you with the additional information that you can provide by editing your question.  Also, does your bike have an aftermarket exhaust system?